# insertCell() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table dynamically with javascript, I want it to have 10 rows and 10 columns. I've had no problem adding the right quantity of rows using insertRow(), but i can't do the same with insertCell().

```
**HTML**
<div class="container-fluid">
<table id="tableMars"> 
</table>
</div>   


**JavaScript**
var mars = document.getElementById("tableMars");


function createMars(){
   for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
      var row = mars.insertRow();
      row.className += "tableRows";
      var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("tableRows");
    }
    for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
      columns.insertCell()
    }
}
```

I expected to add 10 columns to each row but I received the error "insertCell() is not a function" when running the function in the console.

Comment: Should be `collums[j]`

Comment: Thank you! It added a cell, but only one tho. Any other changes I can make to add more?

Comment: *collums* is a **live** collection, so you only need to get it once. Assigning to it on each iteration is just a waste of processor ticks. ;-) You don't need *collums* anyway, *mars.rows* will return a list of all the rows, so just iterate over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until the table exists before calling *getElementById*.

You can also add the cells to the rows in the same loop, so you don't need *columns*. If you want to get a collection of the table's rows, use its *rows* property (i.e. `mars.rows`).

*document.getElementsByClassName* returns a live collection, so you only need to call it once, not on every iteration of the loop. But as noted above, you don't need *columns* anyway. And avoid global variables where possible, so pass *mars* to the function.

Below is a slight refactoring of your code that "works".

```js
function createMars(mars){

  // Insert 10 rows
  for (var i=0, row; i<10; i++){
    row = mars.insertRow();
    row.className += "tableRows";

    // For each row, insert 10 cells
    for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
      row.insertCell()
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var mars = document.getElementById("tableMars");
  createMars(mars);
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.tableRows {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableMars"> 
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You receive the error, because `columns` returns a HTMLCollection of multiple elements. What you need is a loop:

```js
var mars = document.getElementById("tableMars");

function createMars() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var row = mars.insertRow();
    row.className += "tableRows";
    var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("tableRows");
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    for (let column of columns) {
      column.insertCell();
    }
  }
}

createMars();
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table id="tableMars">
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Column, Add Row, Delete Column, Delete Row. **Simplest way**

```js
    function addColumn(myTable) {
      var table = document.getElementById(myTable);
      var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      for(i=0;i<row.length;i++){
       row[i].innerHTML = row[i].innerHTML + '<td></td>';
      }
    }
    function deleterow(tblId)
    {
     
      var table = document.getElementById(tblId);
      var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        if(row.length!='1'){
       row[row.length - 1].outerHTML='';
            }
    }
    function deleteColumn(tblId)
    {
     var allRows = document.getElementById(tblId).rows;
     for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
      if (allRows[i].cells.length > 1) {
       allRows[i].deleteCell(-1);
      }
     }
    }
    function myFunction(myTable) {
      var table = document.getElementById(myTable);
      var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      var row = row[row.length-1].outerHTML;
      table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML + row;
      var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      var row = row[row.length-1].getElementsByTagName('td');
      for(i=0;i<row.length;i++){
       row[i].innerHTML = '';
      }
    }
```

```css
    table, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    td {
      cursor:text;
      padding:10px;
    }
    td:empty:after{
      content:"Type here...";
      color:#cccccc;
    }
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="+Column" onclick="addColumn('tblSample')">
    <input type="button" value="-Column" onclick="deleteColumn('tblSample')">
    <input type="button" value="+Row" onclick="myFunction('tblSample')">
    <input type="button" value="-Row" onclick="deleterow('tblSample')">
    </p>
    <table><tbody id="tblSample" contenteditable><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```